# signing apk with "test/development" key

Tags: android

the way i prepare my app for deployment is by using the Eclipse and exporting the signed APK (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)).

However, I've gotten reports that my app is not searcheable on the Market with devices that have test/development/unofficial ROM flashed.

Does anyone know how i can make the app visible for all android devices (production and development)?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Alternatively, if you don't want to put it on the market, you can also put it on a website for anyone to download.